# .Net Core 5 Post Response returns Incorrect Content-Type: application/json

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

Using .Net Core 5, I have configured my application with the necessary packages needed to make work of application/json.

Using the [FromBody] parameter attribute, and posting the data using postman results in the following error:

Incorrect Content-Type: application/json

I have already configured the AddControllers(...) method in startup with the .AddNewtonsoftJson(...).

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default
        }).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
       options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
          new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

Below is the code from the controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] ProjectRequest pr)
    {
        try
        {
            var proj = new Project
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Name = pr.Name,
                Excerpt = pr.Excerpt,
                Tags = pr.Tags
            };

            var resp = new
            {
                Data = "Project Added successfully"
            };

            return Ok(resp);

        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            var br = new
            {
                Data = $"An error occured : {e.Message}"
            };

            return BadRequest(br);
        }
    }
```

I cannot figure out why this error is still being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Are you correct to post the data with postman, my example can work normally:

Postman:
[image]

Controller:
After sending the data, then the controller receives the data

[image]

Finally received the value

```
 {
     "data": "Project Added successfully"
}
```

[image]